# Can some one please solve what I am doing wrong in jsonp and google

Tags: jquery, jsonp

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",

    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ajax&
          destination=toronto&region=ca&avoid=tolls&sensor=false",

    dataType: "jsonp",

   success: function(jsonp) {

             alert(jsonp);

          console.log(jsonp);
          }


});



});
```

The alert and console.log doesn't work although i have a correct json returned from google.

Comment: Without you telling us what's going wrong.. no

Comment: have you tried debugging it in Firefox using Firebug or in Google Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `error:` callback to see if you're getting an error? Obviously, I'm mind-reading here, so this may not be what you're asking!

Comment: you have to use your api key  in the url.

Comment: one more thing . you can't make cross domain ajax request. (in standard browser)

Comment: Also, looks like you have an error in your syntax around the first `});` bit. That should not have a semicolon since it is in an object literal.

Comment: Thanks but still i dont know why i cant have alert box poppin up. Although i can see the response in firebug 100% ok in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have linebreaks in strings.

Besides that, that Google service responds with plain JSON - not JSONP.
Unless they support JSONP you are out of luck. And if they do so, you need to specify the an argument containing the name of the callback function.

Comment: Or, you can append `&callback=?` to the request URI and jQuery will generate a unique function name for the JSONP request. (Assuming Google's API supports JSONP)

Answer (score 1):

drop the jsonp specification.

```
  $.ajax({

    type: "GET",

    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ajax&  destination=toronto&region=ca&avoid=tolls&sensor=false",
   success: function(json) {
             alert(json.status);
             console.log(json);
          }
});
```

Comment: then you would have cross-domain issues.